# How can I drop a row if all values in a given set of columns are 0

Tags: python, pandas, drop

I have a dataframe with about 8000 records that I would like to go through and drop all rows where columns 1/1/2015 - 1/1/2030 are equal to 0 (columns are labelled as 1/1/2015, 1/1/2016, etc.). Here is my code:

```
find_zeros = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for z in range(2015,2031):
        find_zeros += row['1/1/%s' %(z)]
    if (find_zeros <= 0):
        df.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

I keep running into many issues so I want to know if you know how to make this code work or if there is a better way to do this.

For reference, here is an example of the df:

```
   name      1/1/2015 1/1/2016 1/1/2017
   a           0.0      0.0      0.0
   b           0.0      0.0      1.0
   c           0.0      0.0      0.0
   d           1.0      0.0      0.0
   e           0.0      0.0      1.0
   f           0.0      0.0      0.0
```

Expected outcome:

```
 name      1/1/2015 1/1/2016 1/1/2017
   b           0.0      0.0      1.0
   d           1.0      0.0      0.0
   e           0.0      0.0      1.0
```

Comment: please provide an example df and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can filter to keep values where not [all](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) the values are ([eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)) 0 in the subset of `cols`:

```
cols = [f'1/1/{v}' for v in range(2015, 2018)]  # change upper bound to 2031
df = df[~df[cols].eq(0).all(axis=1)]
```

or where [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) are not equal ([ne](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html)) to 0 in the subset:

```
cols = [f'1/1/{v}' for v in range(2015, 2018)]  # change upper bound to 2031
df = df[df[cols].ne(0).any(axis=1)]
```

---

*Note if creating a new DataFrame from this selection:

```
new_df = df[df[cols].ne(0).any(axis=1)]
```

`copy` or `reset_index` or `loc` will be needed to avoid a later `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

For example,

```
new_df = df[df[cols].ne(0).any(axis=1)].copy()
```

---

Sample Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f'},
    '1/1/2015': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0},
    '1/1/2016': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0},
    '1/1/2017': {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 0.0}
})
```

```
  name  1/1/2015  1/1/2016  1/1/2017
0    a       0.0       0.0       0.0
1    b       0.0       0.0       1.0
2    c       0.0       0.0       0.0
3    d       1.0       0.0       0.0
4    e       0.0       0.0       1.0
5    f       0.0       0.0       0.0
```

Sample Output:

```
  name  1/1/2015  1/1/2016  1/1/2017
1    b       0.0       0.0       1.0
3    d       1.0       0.0       0.0
4    e       0.0       0.0       1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, why is it that index 2 gets dropped with a 1? I wouldn't want this to happen.

Comment: I don't understand. You said you wanted the row dropped if all values in the range (2015-2030) are 0. 2013 and 2014 are not in the range 2015-2030? In the context of your sample 2013 and 2014 would be `name` and `name1`.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right. I hadn't noticed you included years outside 2015-2030

Comment: for "cols" do I replace it with '1/1/2015' : '1/1/2030'?

Comment: `cols = [f'1/1/{v}' for v in range(2015, 2031)]` Same range you use in your code just as a comprehension